# How to make PDFs sharper (better readability)?

Tags: windows, software-rec, pdf

I've really badly scanned document in PDF which I would like to enhance (make grey, hardly visible invoice readable).

Is there some free tool, or trial tool that I could use on this one document?

OS is Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a screenshot of it by <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> and paste it in [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/)

Then go to the menu "Image" and apply "sharpen" ( or press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> ) until you achieve the result you need.

Comment: I tried both Shift + S and Shift + U and it seems Shift + U did it better. Tnx!

Answer (score 1):

Cheapest would be to convert the pdf to an image. If you can fit the whole document on your screen without scrolling, just take a screenshot. Then use Irfanview or similar to adjust contrast and brightness to improve the file.

PDFs are not images per se, and so you cannot generally modify them, even with the full-blown pdf apps, like you would images, which is what you are trying to do in this process.

Comment: Tnx. It was single page so screenshot was easiest to go.

Answer (score 1):

As @music2myear has mentioned, taking a screenshot is not a good idea unless you can fit the whole image at 100% on your screen. Taking the screenshot of a smaller version will likely result in lower quality.

I'd suggest

- **extracting the images** using XPDF (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/134869/how-to-extract-image-from-pdf-file/169462#169462) on how to do it)
- and then opening it in [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) to sharpen

Comment: Actually Adobe Acrobat can also convert PDFs into images.

Comment: @TechExpertWizard The user asked for something free. I assume you are referring to Acrobat DC?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to Acrobat DC. BTW the OP said "Is there some free tool, or trial tool that I could use on this one document?" and they included "trial tool," and Acrobat DC has a 7-day free trial.