# Save images from a PDF

Tags: windows, images, pdf, extract

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to extract image from PDF file](https://superuser.com/questions/134869/how-to-extract-image-from-pdf-file)

I have a PDF with images.

I would like to save the images alone as JPG with the resolution as 300.

Please provide me the commands to execute this in Windows.

Comment: I am really curious about those commands and where can one execute them

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick may be the tool you're looking for (there are [Windows binaries available here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)):

```
 convert -resample 300x300 infile.pdf outfile%d.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing a quick google using "command line pdf utility" gives you a few options, some being:

- http://utilitywarrior.com/Image-to-PDF-Command-Line-Tool.htm
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software#Converters

Comment: interesting stuff

Answer (score 1):

a question like this one is asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) before, and this is the question [How to extract image from PDF file](https://superuser.com/questions/134869/how-to-extract-image-from-pdf-file).Below is an answer with commands:

> If you download XPDF for Windows
>   (here), you'll find a few .exe files
>   inside. You can run them without
>   "installation". Use pdfimages.exe like
>   this:
>
> pdfimages.exe -help
>
> This displays the help screen.
>
> pdfimages.exe ^
>
> ```
> -j ^
> c:\path\to\your.pdf ^
> c:\path\to\where\you\want\images\prefix
> ```
>
> This extracts all JPEGs as
>   prefix-00N.jpg, and all the other
>   images as prefix-00N.ppm (Portable
>   PixMap).
>
> pdfimages.exe ^
>
> ```
> -j ^
> -f 11 ^
> -l 13 ^
> c:\path\to\your.pdf ^
> c:\path\to\where\you\want\images\prefix
> ```
>
> Same as before, but limits image
>   extraction to pages 11 ('f' = first)
>   to 13 ('l' = last).